# Best practice for testing object in android. Should I instantiate class in test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, robolectric, dagger-2

Iam currently trying to unit test an application in android. I am using Dagger 2 for DI. I currently have a class called "ErrorChecker" which I use to check if an email is of valid format and password is of certain length etc.

Within my ErrorChecker class is a context which i inject. This is basically only used to get a string resource with a warning IF the entered email was not in the correct format. Id like to be able to inject the context into the version of the ErrorChecker class in my test.  I am not sure if this is absolutely necessary?.  below is my test class.

```
@RunWith(RobolectricGradleTestRunner.class)
@Config(constants = BuildConfig.class)
public class ErrCheckerTest {


private ErrorChecker errchecker;

@Before
public void setup()
{
     errchecker = new ErrorChecker();
     errchecker.setCont(MyApplication.getInst());
}



@Test
public void validEmailTest()
{
   //invalid emails

    errchecker.setEmail("notvalidemail");
    assertFalse(errchecker.emailValid());
    errchecker.setEmail("jimm.***@yahoo.com.com");
    assertFalse(errchecker.emailValid());
    errchecker.setEmail(".*%&$$$$$.@fish.ie");
    assertFalse(errchecker.emailValid());
    errchecker.setEmail("");
    assertFalse(errchecker.emailValid());
    errchecker.setEmail("jimm.@yaaaaaa");
    assertFalse(errchecker.emailValid());


    // valid emails

    errchecker.setEmail("eoin@yahoo.com");
    assertTrue(errchecker.emailValid());
    errchecker.setEmail("eoin@myemail.co.uk");
    assertTrue(errchecker.emailValid());
    errchecker.setEmail("paul.murphy@mygit.ie");
    assertTrue(errchecker.emailValid());
    errchecker.setEmail("karen.greene@hello.ie");
    assertTrue(errchecker.emailValid());
    errchecker.setEmail("orla@yahoo.ie");
    assertTrue(errchecker.emailValid());

  }
}
```

essentially I just instantiate the class rather than injecting it. I also made a method in my ErrorChecker Class so I could set the context. I then pass it a  static Instance of MyApplication using MyApplication.getInst(), which extends the Application class. Iam wondering is this an Okay way to create my ErrorChecker class with the context, or should I try inject it. This will require lot of extra boilerplate code But Will probably look cleaner. Id like to follow best practice so If anyone can tell me if this approach violates best practice, or could suggest a different way of creating the ErrorChecker class in my Test id really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to pass the context in your class ErrorChecker? I think ErrorChecker should only validate if your data are correct or not. Your view should have the responsibility to get and display the message if the data are incorrect.

Comment: yeah your right. i use the context in a lot of my classes to set an error message usually in my Model class. I am trying to make the view class a "dumb" view so I try get it to handle as little logic as possible. therefore I set the Error (which I get from a String resource) in my Model. I could change the code around but then Iam handling non UI logic in the view and that  would violate MVP. Thats my thinking anyway, but Iam open to suggestions always.

Comment: ALso my Tests are in a different package to my main, where all my components etc are. Threrefore I cant Inject my Mocks into my tests as I cant refer to My Test classes in my Main package.

Comment: How do you inject the context into ErrorChecker. Couldn't you inject it into the constructor of ErrorChecker so you could use a mock context in your test.

Comment: cant call "void inject(TestErrorChecker errchecker)" in my component because the Component is in the Main package. So I cant refer to the test class in my Main package as the test is in the Test Package. . Bit of a pain.  I can set up my Module to return a mock context but I need to restructure the whole thing. That or I can try extenting my component in my Test package. see if that works. Its all good fun anyway!